# Ошибка при использовании HAVING

Tags: sql

Есть процедура:

```
SELECT
    NumID,
    SUM(/*рабочий код*/) AS chislo
FROM tabel1
GROUP BY NumID
HAVING chislo > 5
```

Как мне дать название получившемуся числу SUM(---)?

Так как у меня не работает, ошибка в строке с HAVING: Invalid column name 'chislo '.

Comment: О какой СУБД речь? В MySQL такой запрос отработает без ошибок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак

```
SELECT NumID,
SUM(--рабочий код--) as chislo 
FROM tabel1 
GROUP BY NumID 
HAVING SUM(--рабочий код--) > 5
```

Comment: жаль( спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Можно вместо HAVING использовать подзапрос:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
    NumID,
    SUM(--рабочий код--) as chislo 
  FROM tabel1 
  GROUP BY NumID
) t
WHERE chislo > 5
```